# How can I get the previous friday and next thursday given a date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query the previous thursday as well as the next friday given a certain date. If the date passed is friday then `PrevFriday` should be the current date. Similarily if the date passed is thursday then `nextThursday` should be the date that was passed.

I have seen some other solutions on this site that include the use of `WEEKDAY()` offset by some interval but this only works when the date is static. As I am going to be passing a column `WorkDate` through this later I need this to work for every date and not just specific dates.

I currently have a query that works ONLY for today and not a range of dates.

1.

```
SELECT '2019-05-16' + INTERVAL -3 - weekday('2019-05-16') DAY AS PrevFriday,
       '2019-05-16' + INTERVAL 3 - weekday('2019-05-16') DAY AS NextThursday
```

This code outputs the expected result but if we change the date we are passing to tomorrow:

2.

```
SELECT '2019-05-17' + INTERVAL -3 - weekday('2019-05-17') DAY AS PrevFriday,
       '2019-05-17' + INTERVAL 3 - weekday('2019-05-17') DAY AS NextThursday
```

The EXPECTED output for the first piece of code:

`PrevFriday -> 2019-05-10`, 
`NextThursday -> 2019-05-16`

The EXPECTED output for the second piece of code:

`PrevFriday -> 2019-05-17`, 
`NextThursday -> 2019-05-23`

But the ACTUAL results are:

`PrevFriday -> 2019-05-10`, 
`NextThursday -> 2019-05-16`

Comment: 2019-05-17 is a Friday.  The weekday function for Friday returns 4. So 2019-05-17 -3 -4 does in fact = 2019-05-10.

Comment: @Andrew yes but because the date passed is friday, I am trying to return the current date instead of last weeks friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
select t.*
    , t.dt + interval (7 + 3 - weekday(t.dt)) % 7 day as NextThursday
    , t.dt - interval (7 - 4 + weekday(t.dt)) % 7 day as PrevFriday
from test t
```

The main idea is to use the modulo operator `% 7`, so we never add or subtract more than 6 days.

Test Data:

```
create table test(
  d char(2),
  dt date
);
insert into test(d, dt) values
('mo', '2019-05-13'),
('tu', '2019-05-14'),
('we', '2019-05-15'),
('th', '2019-05-16'),
('fr', '2019-05-17'),
('su', '2019-05-18'),
('so', '2019-05-19');
```

Result:

```
d  | dt         | NextThursday | PrevFriday
---|------------|--------------|-----------
mo | 2019-05-13 |   2019-05-16 | 2019-05-10
tu | 2019-05-14 |   2019-05-16 | 2019-05-10
we | 2019-05-15 |   2019-05-16 | 2019-05-10
th | 2019-05-16 |   2019-05-16 | 2019-05-10
fr | 2019-05-17 |   2019-05-23 | 2019-05-17
su | 2019-05-18 |   2019-05-23 | 2019-05-17
so | 2019-05-19 |   2019-05-23 | 2019-05-17
```

[db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i2XVc8A4rL39aMfWhM91ux/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF WEEKDAY(DateVar) = 4 then --Friday logic
    PrevFriday = DateVar
    NextThursday =  DATE_ADD(DateVar, INTERVAL 6 DAY);
ELSEIF WEEKDAY(DateVar) = 3 THEN --Thursday logic
    PrevFriday = DATE_ADD(DateVar, INTERVAL -6 DAY)
    NextThursday = DateVar;
ELSE
    -- logic to ind the Prev Friday and Next Thursday;
```